# If ${p_{n}}$ is a sequence in a compact metric space $X$, then some subsequence of ${p_{n}}$ converges to a point of $X$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, analysis, elementary-set-theory

This has been proved in Rudin, but I am trying a different approach. Please suggest me how to prove this with my approach. I have done till the following.

Since $X$ is compact, every open cover of $X$ has a finite subcover. Lets assume $\{{U_{j}}\}$ be a finite subcover of X where $j=1,2,3....,n$.

$\{p_{n}\}$ is in $X$. So it admits the finite subcover ${U_{j}}$. Also any subsequence $\{p_{n_{i}}\}$ of ${p_{n}}$ will also admit the same subcover.

$\cup{U_{j}}$ is also an open cover of $\{p_{n_{i}}\}$.

So $\exists B_{r}(p)$ such that $\cup{U_{j}}\subset B_{r}(p)$, where $p$ is a point in $X$.

So, $d(p_{n_{i}},p)<r$.

But how do I prove that $d(p_{n_{i}},p)<r$ for all $r>0$? If I do this, then $p$ will be a limit of $\{p_{n_{i}}\}$ and hence $\{p_{n_{i}}\}$ will converge.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're going backwards, what you're doing is grabing some random subsequence and then trying to put it inside an open ball. What you should do is, grab an open cover (of balls of radius r) then prove that infinitely many $p_n$ must fall inside some ball, this should be easy. Once you're there you have your subsequence falling inside that ball. Now, rinse and repeat, using the closure of the balls and grabbing a ball smaller inside your ball and using the closure to get a closed set, repeat infinitely many times with radius going to $0$, then use the Cantor's intersection theorem for closed sets to get a limit point.

Answer (score 0):

What you've written so far doesn't really make sense.

> Since X is compact, every open cover of X has a finite subcover. Lets assume {Uj} be a finite subcover of X where j=1,2,3....,n.

When you talk about a "finite subcover," you have to have some original cover that you're taking a subcover of.  You haven't specified the original cover here, so I don't know what I'm taking a finite subcover of.

The whole point of compactness arguments is that you *first* build an infinite cover in a clever way, and then use compactness to show that a finite number of the sets from your original covering will suffice.

Comment: I assume that $\{{U_{i}}\}$, where $i$ runs over $N$ is an open cover and this assumption is valid since $X$ is compact.

Comment: Any cover?  So $U_1 = X$, $U_2 = X$, $U_3 = X$, ...?